# Hierarchical Reference to subplots of a pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, labels, cleveref

I have 4 plots, depicting three subtle different behaviors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
t    phi
0    5
10   15
20   25
30   20
40   35
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
                    label style={font=\tiny},
                    tick label style={font=\tiny}
}, width=0.3\textwidth}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group name=my plots,group size= 2 by
      2, vertical sep=1.5cm },height=5cm,width=6.4cm]

  \nextgroupplot
  \addplot [color=blue] table [x={t}, y={phi}] {testdata.dat};
  \label{plot:1}

  \nextgroupplot
  \addplot [color=green] table [x={t}, y={phi}] {testdata.dat};
  \label{plot:2}

  \nextgroupplot
  \addplot [color=red] table [x={t}, y={phi}] {testdata.dat};
  \label{plot:3}

  \nextgroupplot
  \addplot [color=blue] table [x={t}, y={phi}] {testdata.dat};
  \label{plot:4}
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{fig:plots}
\caption{Some Plots}
\end{figure}

As you can see in \Cref{plot:1,plot:3} \ldots
\end{document}
```

The thing is, I want them to be plotted next to each other in order to show their (sometimes subtle) differences. In the text to follow, however, I need to reference each subplot **individually**. Hence, I would like to label them with numbers, letters or whatever and later on `\Cref{}` them.
This reference should be resolved in a hierarchical manner, i.e. it should read something like "Figure 1, Plot 2".

Is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
t    phi
0    5
10   15
20   25
30   20
40   35
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  every axis/.append style={
      label style={font=\tiny},
      tick label style={font=\tiny}
     },
  width=0.3\textwidth,
}


\newcounter{plot}[figure]

\newcommand{\AddLabel}[1]{%
\node [below right] at (rel axis cs:0,1) {\refstepcounter{plot}\label{#1}\ref{#1})};
}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{plot}{plot}{plots}
\Crefname{plot}{Plot}{Plots}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group name=my plots,group size= 2 by
      2, vertical sep=1.5cm },height=5cm,width=6.4cm]

  \nextgroupplot
  \addplot [color=blue] table [x={t}, y={phi}] {testdata.dat};
  \AddLabel{plot:1}

  \nextgroupplot
  \addplot [color=green] table [x={t}, y={phi}] {testdata.dat};
  \AddLabel{plot:2}

  \nextgroupplot
  \addplot [color=red] table [x={t}, y={phi}] {testdata.dat};
  \AddLabel{plot:3}

  \nextgroupplot
  \addplot [color=blue] table [x={t}, y={phi}] {testdata.dat};
  \AddLabel{plot:4}
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{fig:plots}
\caption{Some Plots}
\end{figure}

As you can see in \Cref{plot:1,plot:3} \ldots
\end{document}
```

Comment: That solves the problem about referencing them at all. Thanks. Do you know, if it is possible to reference them hierarchically? (i.e. get "Plots 1 and 2 in Figure 1" automatically?)

Comment: @choeger No, I don't, sorry.  You'd need to do `\cref{plot:1,plot:2} in \cref{fig:1}` with my code.

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution using the `\phantomsubcaption` and `\subref` commands from the `subcaption` package. It does not exactly do what you want, but I think this gives shorter labels and so is worth showing it.

For simplicity I created the new command `\SubLabel` to place the labels, so they always appear the same.

```
    \begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
        t    phi
        0    5
        10   15
        20   25
        30   20
        40   35
    \end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{
        groupplots,
    }
\usepackage{cleveref}
    \newcommand*\SubLabel[1]{
        \node [
            anchor=north west,
            text width=2em,
            text height=2ex,
            text depth=1ex,
            align=left,
        ] at (axis description cs:0.02,0.98)
            {\phantomsubcaption\label{#1}\subref{#1})};
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{groupplot}[
                group style={
                    group name=my plots,
                    group size= 2 by 2,
                    vertical sep=1.5cm,
                },
                height=5cm,
                width=6.4cm,
            ]
            \nextgroupplot
                \addplot [color=blue] table [x={t}, y={phi}] {testdata.dat};
                    \SubLabel{plot:1};
            \nextgroupplot
                \addplot [color=green] table [x={t}, y={phi}] {testdata.dat};
                    \SubLabel{plot:2};
            \nextgroupplot
                \addplot [color=red] table [x={t}, y={phi}] {testdata.dat};
                    \SubLabel{plot:3};
            \nextgroupplot
                \addplot [color=blue] table [x={t}, y={phi}] {testdata.dat};
                    \SubLabel{plot:4};
            \end{groupplot}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Some Plots}
            \label{fig:plots}
    \end{figure}

    As you can see in \crefrange{plot:1}{plot:3} \ldots
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]